# HTTP Get request to IP-based host using Indy

Tags: http, delphi, indy

I have some Delphi code that connects to a servlet and I´m trying to switch from TIdTCPClient to TIdHTTP.

I connect to the servlet this way

```
   try
      lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create( nil );
      responseStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      lHTTP.Get(HttpMsg, responseStream);
      SetString( html, PAnsiChar(responseStream.Memory), responseStream.Size);
      AnotarMensaje( odDepurar, 'IMPFIS: Impresora fiscal reservada ' + html );
```

Where HttpMsg is `localhost:6080/QRSRPServer/PedirImpresion?usuarioDMS=hector`

All I´m getting is

```
GET localhost:6080/QRSRPServer/PedirImpresion?usuarioDMS=hector HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/html
Accept: text/html, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

The HTTP dialog that I had before was like this

```
GET /QRSRPServer/PedirImpresion?usuarioDMS=hector HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:6080

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

So, I try to add the Host header, with this host: `localhost:6080`

```
   try
      lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create( nil );
      lHTTP.Host := Host;
      responseStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      lHTTP.Get(HttpMsg, responseStream);
      SetString( html, PAnsiChar(responseStream.Memory), responseStream.Size);
      AnotarMensaje( odDepurar, 'IMPFIS: Impresora fiscal reservada ' + html );
```

And I get

```
Socket Error # 11004
```

Comment: What version of Indy are you using? The behavior you describe is not how `TIdHTTP` behaves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where HttpMsg is `localhost:6080/QRSRPServer/PedirImpresion?usuarioDMS=hector`

`HttpMsg` **must** begin with `http://` or `https://`:

```
http://localhost:6080/QRSRPServer/PedirImpresion?usuarioDMS=hector
```

You should be getting an `EIdUnknownProtocol` exception raised when `TIdHTTP` parses the URL and sees the missing protocol scheme.

`TIdHTTP` should always be sending a `Host` header, but especially for an HTTP 1.1 request, but you claim it is not.  This is why you are getting a `Bad Request` error,  because HTTP 1.1 servers are required to reject an HTTP 1.1 request that omits that header.

You also claim that `TIdHTTP` is including the host and port values in the `GET` line.  The *ONLY* time it ever does that is when connecting to a host through an HTTP proxy, but I don't see you configuring the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` property at all.

In short, `TIdHTTP` should not be behaving the way you claim.

The correct solution is to make sure you are passing a *full* URL to `TIdHTTP.Get()`.

On a side note, your code requires `html` to be an `AnsiString`. You should change it to a standard `string` (which is `AnsiString` in D2007 and earlier) and let `TIdHTTP` return a `string` for you, then you don't need the `TMemoryStream` anymore:

```
html := lHTTP.Get(HttpMsg);
```

Comment: No, I´m not claiming that TIdHTTP is including the host and port, I´m saying that I´m trying to do a GET to this URL: `localhost:6080/QRSRPServer/PedirImpresion?usuarioDMS=hector` so the host and port are already there.

I corrected my URL to include hhtp:// and removed the host and port manual configuration and it worked like a charm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought. I was assuming that having a "host" paremeter that included the port would be enough but looking at a Wireshark capture I saw it was sending everything over the standard HTTP port.

So this did the trick

```
try
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create( nil );
  lHTTP.Host := GatewayIp;
  lHTTP.Port := GatewayPuerto;
  responseStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
  lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Host: ' + Host );
  lHTTP.Get(HttpMsg, responseStream);
  SetString( html, PAnsiChar(responseStream.Memory), responseStream.Size);
  AnotarMensaje( odDepurar, 'IMPFIS: Impresora fiscal reservada ' + html );
```

Comment: `TIdHTTP` parses the `Host` and `Port` from the provided URL. DO NOT set those properties manually. The correct solution is to make sure `HttpMsg` is properly formatted to begin with, which includes prefixing it with `http://` or `https://`